# Why there is no script error is thrown, when NULL object property is accessed in MXML

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

We can add inline codes in MXML. However we when try to get properties from NULL object in MXML(inline code), flex doesn't throw error. However when we do same thing in action script tag, we can see script error thrown.

how this behavior is captured in MXML. Any idea.

For eg:

```
Class ValueTo  //Model class
{

  public var name:string;

}

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var v:ValueTo;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Label **text="{v.lable}"** />  //No error thrown, when v=null, i.e null.label
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is due to the curly brace expression: `text="{v.label}`.  (I never know what to call these other than "curly brace" or binding expressions - someone please edit/correct me with the proper term).

The Flex data binding feature "swallows" these errors by design.  As you can imagine, values like `v.label` can be null, for example, when the application is starting up. As a convenience, Flex takes care of these errors for us. But we don't have that same luxury when we write our own Actionscript.

It's nothing magical, however. The Flex code that manages data binding/curly brace expressions is either checking for nulls or is wrapped in `try/catch` statements to handle any errors that may result from null objects.